# How to stop giving very small value to zero in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, rounding, precision

Say I have a matrix M (3x3)

```
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    0.0100000000000000
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    1
1.15740740740741e-17    1.15740740740741e-18    0.1
```

If I output M(1,1:2), it is

```
ans =
   1.0e-16 *
   0.115740740740741   0.011574074074074
```

However, it gives zero for the first two column if I do M(1,1:3)

```
ans =
   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.010000000000000
```

No sure how to stop this from happening. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: `format long g`

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked!

Comment: Any scientific notation format will work. You can also use `format shortE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `*G` versions of [`format`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) which allows the display format to be adaptive and use the most appropriate for each element. There are two variants

```
format shortG

%   1.1574e-17   1.1574e-18         0.01
%   1.1574e-17   1.1574e-18            1
%   1.1574e-17   1.1574e-18          0.1
```

Or

```
format longG

%      1.15740740740741e-17      1.15740740740741e-18                      0.01
%      1.15740740740741e-17      1.15740740740741e-18                         1
%      1.15740740740741e-17      1.15740740740741e-18                       0.1
```